# Upgrade path for service fabric from 5.7.198 to 6.0

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Recently we started getting a message on the Azure portal that our SF version on the cluster we use will become unsupported  (5.7.198). Which I interpret as that we need to upgrade to 6.0.

1. Has anyone done such an upgrade on a prod system with real customers and data that should be kept safe?
2. Is there an upgrade we should follow (i.e. go through intermediate versions)
3. Any issues that I should expect?

Thanks!

Comment: This is more of a question for https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Good point - 10x!

Comment: I hope you found this document too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-upgrade